# How to conditionally return specific value with another in JSONPath?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I've got an object like this one:

```json
{
    "content": {
        "iteration_size": 1
    }
}
```

I need a JSONPath which returns `null` if the value of `next_item` is exactly 1, or the value of `iteration_size` otherwise. So the above should return `null` and `"iteration_size": 2` should return 2. Is this possible in JSONPath?

I've tried variations on `$.content[?(@.iteration_size == 1)].iteration_size`, but the two online evaluators I've tried even disagree on the results of several of my attempts.

The use case is the AWS Batch API, where the [array size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/array_jobs.html) must be either `null` or a number between 2 and 10,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Support suggested that this was not possible, and that I should instead use a branch in the step function. I ended up replacing this:

```
.next(batch_submit_job)
[…]
```

with this:

```
.next(
    aws_stepfunctions.Choice(self, "check_maybe_array")
    .when(
        aws_stepfunctions.Condition.number_equals("$.content.iteration_size", 1),
        single_batch_submit_job,
    )
    .otherwise(array_batch_submit_job)
    .afterwards()
)
```

where only `array_batch_submit_job` has an `array_size`. Note how the rest of the step function ended up wrapped *inside* the last `next()` call rather than at the top level.